# read sequence of hex values from ifstream using std::copy

Tags: c++

Consider a file containing a sequence of integers expressed in hex notation.  I can stream them in like this:

```
using namespace std;
ifstream infile(fname);
unsigned int i;
vector<unsigned int> vals;
while (infile >> std::hex >> i){
    vals.push_back(i);
}
```

What if I want to do the same thing with an `istream_iterator`?

```
/// borks on hex:
copy(istream_iterator<unsigned int>(infile),
    istream_iterator<unsigned int>(), back_inserter(ref_data));
```

Is there a way to tell the `istream_iterator` how to assume hex notation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same way:

```
copy(istream_iterator<unsigned int>(infile >> std::hex),
     istream_iterator<unsigned int>(),
     back_inserter(ref_data));
```

Comment: In retrospect, that was pretty obvious...  Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing a strange issue, where this works for the first 275 elements in the file, but iteration just stops there. The remaining 100,000 or so elements are not copied.